# Transposing Lists - Python

Tags: python

I have list `a = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]` and want to convert that into list `b = [[1,4,7],[2,5,8],[3,6,9]]`. Is it possible to do that?

i.e. take all the value in the first element spot and combine into a new list, same for 2nd, 3rd etc...

Assume the initial list has an unknown amount of elements and each element has unknown length, i.e. there could be 40 elements in a and each element contains 14 numbers. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do it.

The first one is as follows:

`print(list(map(list, zip(*a))))`

another option is using `numpy` as follows:

`print(np.array(a).T.tolist())`

Another option is to use list comprehension as follows:

`print([[row[i] for row in a] for i in range(len(a[0]))])`

Answer (score 1):

Using numpy you can try this

```
import numpy as np


a= [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
ar = np.array(a)
a_transpose = at.T.tolist()
```